# How do control buttons know they've been clicked?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, message-queue, touchscreen

I have written an application in c++ visual studio 6 that looks for the WM_LBUTTONDOWN message to carry out a certain task. This works fine except when using a touchscreen. The Wm_lbuttondown or any other button message is not sent when the screen is touched. However, the control buttons still operate normally, so they know they are being clicked. I would like to know how the buttons detect the touch. I would like to detect when the screen is touched in a similar way to how I detect a mouse click. Is there a different WM I can use other than WM_LBUTTONDOWN?
My old version of visual studio doesn't seem to recognise WM_TOUCH so I haven't been able to try that.

Comment: By default, touch input generates compatibility mouse input messages, unless you opt out of this behavior by calling [`RegisterTouchWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow). The logic to determine whether a button has been clicked is implemented in the `BUTTON` window class. When it is it sends a [`BN_CLICKED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bn-clicked) notification to its parent window. It doesn't matter whether the button was clicked using a mouse, keyboard, or touch input device.

Comment: I recommend getting rid of Visual Studio 6 and upgrade to Visual Studio 2022. Visual Studio 6 was great 20 years ago, but now it's obsolete, hence the impossibility to use symbols such as `WM_TOUCH` etc.

Comment: Right, VC++6 is pretty out of place today. Today, we want our software bloated, slow, with user-hostile interfaces, keyboard or otherwise, unpredictable and sluggish. VC++6 doesn't fit any of those categories.

Comment: @IInspectable totally agree, but unfortunately VC6 is now outdated and you can't even install it on a modern computer. But admittedly the VC2022 debugger is really good and so is the editor and even the C++ compiler is OK and complying to standards. BTW Turbo C was also great in the 80s

Comment: @Jabberwocky, I still use VS6 on a modern pc with win10. It works still perfectly for me, (one click, already finished compiled &linked). Need it for some machine applications, which still runs under Win2k PC. And yes "modern* stuff like`WM_TOUCH`  symbols are not available under VS6, but he can use here `BN_CLICKED` instead.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ah, Turbo C!!!! I had that!!!! 

Comment: @TomTom I've tried to install VS6 on a win7 PC a cope of years ago and it didn't work. I wonder how you could install it on a W10 PC.

Comment: I still don't understand how the button gets sent a BN_CLICKED notification when no WM_LBUTTONDOWN is being sent.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Install VS6 on Win10: I followed this steps: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1191047/Install-Visual-Studio-on-Windows). 
Written by Kirk Stowell, the CEO of codejock. Simple and straightforward.

Comment: @DavidHarvey: Show us the code. If you use `RegisterTouchWindow(hWnd,0)` then it is already translated to `BN_CLICKED` under the hood, I think.

Comment: Tom Tom, I haven't used RegisterTouchWindow. In the code I use Peekmessage to look for WM_LBUTTONDOWN. It has worked fine for years until some users started using touchscreen tablet devices. The PeekMessage line is not detecting a WM_LBUTTONDOWN when the screen is touched in the active window. I have now found a work around, but would like to understand how the "under the hood" code produces a BN_CLICKED but I can't get PeekMessage to detect a LBUTTONDOWN. I assumed the BN_CLICKED was triggered by the system receiving a WM_LBUTTONDOWN with perhaps a WM_LBUTTONUP